# How to reduce the use of `echo` in a bash script?

Tags: shell, echo

My bash script contains the following line:

```
echo $(echo "$STRING_VAR" | cut -d' ' -f 2) >> $FILE
```

Here we have two `echo` calls, but are they really necessary ?

I wrote them, because otherwise the bash would think the string in first place is a command.

Comment: Doesn't `echo "$STRING_VAR" | cut -d' ' -f 2 >> $FILE` do what you're expecting ?

Comment: Oh, of course, you're right. I knew my code smelled, but did not see the point - thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply `echo "$STRING_VAR" | cut -d' ' -f 2 >> $FILE` does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "$STRING_VAR" | cut -d' ' -f 2 >> $FILE
```

should be all you need

Answer (score 1):

Also, bash has the handy "here-string" redirection mode: you don't need echo at all:

```
cut -d' ' -f2 <<< "$STRING_VAR" >> "$FILE"
```